# How do I buy all tracks

Tags: trials-frontier

My in game shop used to sell me tracks from past events for 40 gems. Now tracks don't show up there anymore. Using the [trackmap](http://trialstrackmap.sb-f.de/) I created a list of the tracks I am missing:

- Slick Slalom
- Leaping Hollows
- Metal Mayhem
- All 13 tracks from Halloween 2015

Can I still get these tracks some how? And if so how?